# How can I type a word Google Keyboard 5.0.25 doesn't know without being auto-corrected?

Tags: auto-correct, gboard

Google Keyboard 5.0.25 has made it inordinately difficult and frequently apparently impossible for me to type words I want to type that it doesn't yet recognise, and I need your help.

Google Keyboard 4 used to have a pretty good auto-correct scheme: it was fairly relaxed and *usually* did nothing, but if it auto-corrected a word and I didn't want that auto-correction, I could hit backspace and the word would *immediately* revert to *exactly* what I typed. Then I went on typing with it learning my new word.

That backspace reversion seems to have gone away in version 5 on my Nexus 6p and is causing me a lot of trouble.

- When I type a long word it doesn't recognise, it'll *probably* auto-correct that word to something I didn't want. If I hit backspace, *the word stays that way.* So, instead, now I have to backspace further into the word until I reach some compatible beginning portion, and re-type what I wanted, and it won't auto-correct that time.
- Many short words are apparently impossible to type out. Let's take my attempt to write `Kyon` for example: `K` gets no suggestion; `Ky` and `Kyo` would be auto-corrected to `My`; `Kyon` in full would be auto-corrected to `Lion`. Once it auto-corrects to either `My` or `Lion` there's nothing left to backspace into (the first portion of the word's gone). Attempts to reposition the cursor or just go `K` <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>backspace</kbd> `yon` get subjected to the same auto-corrections.

After making that `Kyon` attempt about ten or fifteen times to figure out how the heck I'm supposed to get it to stick, Google Keyboard eventually started suggesting `Lyon` instead, which I could work with.

**What am I meant to do if I want to type a word exactly as-is without auto-correction?** I still want auto-correction on in general — I just want to be able to tell Google Keyboard "no, don't correct this one, thanks", and my old method for doing that isn't working now.

(Specifically the version number is: 5.0.25.122319759-arm64-v8a.)

Comment: There was an update to v5.1.23 on June 15th (probably right after you've posted your issue here) which most likely solved the issue for you already. You could post that as answer and mark it accepted.